# what does tf.app.flags do? why we need that?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm reading the tensorflow tutorial file `fully_connected_feed.py`  which contains the following code. I do not understand what those mean.  Why do we need that? It seems that it's just defining some global variables. Why not just define those directly? Any help is  appreciated. thanks

```
flags = tf.app.flags
FLAGS = flags.FLAGS
flags.DEFINE_float('learning_rate', 0.01, 'Initial learning rate.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('max_steps', 2000, 'Number of steps to run trainer.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden1', 128, 'Number of units in hidden layer 1.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('hidden2', 32, 'Number of units in hidden layer 2.')
flags.DEFINE_integer('batch_size', 100, 'Batch size.  '
                     'Must divide evenly into the dataset sizes.')
flags.DEFINE_string('train_dir', 'data', 'Directory to put the training data.')
flags.DEFINE_boolean('fake_data', False, 'If true, uses fake data '
                     'for unit testing.')
```

Answer (score 13):

This is google's way for parsing arguments from the commandline.  Have a look at [python-gflags](https://github.com/google/python-gflags).  As far as I'm aware, google is the primary user of this commandline parsing library.  The rest of the world uses [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) these days.

But basically, the "tl;dr;" is that you're right -- They are setting up global data.  However, it's global data that can be fiddled with via the commandline.

Comment: This answer got me clear more than the one linked in the question.